# AWS-SAM Python Lambda Function telling me it can't import the module for the function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Writing an AWS-SAM based application and when I try running the lambda function, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 's3-logging/upload': No module named 'lambdas'
```

I've tried a ton of combos of CodeURI and handler, but can't seem to figure it out. My Googling has told me that the lambda container mounts the code **located at CodeURI**. So, in order to reference it, I need to have the handler relative to the directory in CodeURI.

I'm building/staging/deploying it with the AWS-SAM CLI.

Template File:

```
DataBucketS3LoggingFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: s3-logging/upload.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: ./lambdas
```

Directory Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Did you try `CodeUri: lambdas/s3-logging/` and `Handler: upload.lambda_handler`?

Comment: @jarmod, ill give that a shot. I may have tried it before.